# Any way to get notification that UIImagePickerController is about to fire the flash?

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

Apart from rebuilding my camera with AVFoundation, i was curious if i can be notified that the cameraDevice has decided to use flash, which sort of draws out the photo taking process. I have a shutter animation that wants to shut at the moment the camera fires, but the flash screws it up since it keeps the camera open a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply disabling flash does not do for the purpose? If it does,

```
captureDevice.flashMode = AVCaptureFlashModeOff
```

should do. (`captureDevice` is an instance of `AVCaptureDevice`)

Comment: The trick is, i'd like to use the flash, but want to know when it's needed. So, in flash auto mode, there must be some notice that the scene is too dark?